# DI two different concrete implementations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ioc-container

In my quest to fully understand dependency injection containers, I thought of this scenerio:

```
public interface I{
    String exampleAction();
}
public class ConcreteA implements I{
    @Override
    String exampleAction(){return "A";}
}
public class ConcreteB implements I{
    @Override
    String exampleAction(){return "B";}
}
public class Start{
    public static void main(){
        IoC.register<ConcreteA>().as<I>();
    }
    new ActualQuestion(IoC.Resolve<I>(),IoC.Resolve<I>());
}
public class ActualQuestion{
    private I first;
    private I second;
    public ActualQuestion(I needA,I needB){
        first=needA;
        second=needB;
    }
}
```

does this situation just never occur in good code? I feel like it would at some point

Comment: it is possible to have multiple dependencies on the same interface, you just need to provide different qualifiers, but problem with your approach that your "ActualQuestion" depends on implementation, not on interfaces, this usually sign of bad design

Comment: also note, idea of dependency injection is that container injects dependencies into object, in your example object retrieves it's dependencies, it is not DI

Comment: To add to the previous comment, your code is "like" DI, you're using the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Comment: I'm aware that my toy example isn't using DI (constructor or setter) I was just trying to ask if this was possible with the container frameworks

Comment: @IlyaBursov your first comment really is the answer to this question, because I tried to revise my question to an example where I needed two different concrete classes registered to the same interface, and could think of one where the code using the interface wouldn't rely on concrete implementation. If you'd like, you could reiterate this in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Normally this is solved with something like @Qualifier where the qualifier is used to distinguish in some way between different implementations of I